# Error in Placeholder size and type in Tensorflow using CNN and LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, conv-neural-network

I combined CNN and LSTM using this code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import itertools

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import tensorflow as tf
import pyfftw
from scipy import signal
import xlrd
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph
from tensorflow.python.tools import optimize_for_inference_lib
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

##matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('ggplot')


## define funtions
def read_data(file_path):
##    column_names = ['user-id','activity','timestamp', 'x-axis', 'y-axis', 'z-axis']
    column_names = ['activity','timestamp', 'Ax', 'Ay', 'Az', 'Lx', 'Ly', 'Lz', 'Gx', 'Gy', 'Gz', 'Mx', 'My', 'Mz'] ## 3 sensors
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path,header = None, names = column_names)
    return data

def feature_normalize(dataset):
    mu = np.mean(dataset,axis = 0)
    sigma = np.std(dataset,axis = 0)
    return (dataset - mu)/sigma

def plot_axis(ax, x, y, title):
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.set_ylim([min(y) - np.std(y), max(y) + np.std(y)])
    ax.set_xlim([min(x), max(x)])
    ax.grid(True)

def plot_activity(activity,data):
    fig, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows = 3, figsize = (15, 10), sharex = True)
    plot_axis(ax0, data['timestamp'], data['Ax'], 'x-axis')
    plot_axis(ax1, data['timestamp'], data['Ay'], 'y-axis')
    plot_axis(ax2, data['timestamp'], data['Az'], 'z-axis')
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.2)
    fig.suptitle(activity)
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.90)
    plt.show()

def windows(data, size):
    start = 0
    while start < data.count():
        yield start, start + size
        start += (size / 2)

def segment_signal(data, window_size = None, num_channels=None): # edited
    segments = np.empty((0,window_size,num_channels)) #change from 3 to 9 channels for AGM fusion #use variable num_channels=9
    labels = np.empty((0))
    for (n_start, n_end) in windows(data['timestamp'], window_size):
##        x = data["x-axis"][start:end]
##        y = data["y-axis"][start:end]
##        z = data["z-axis"][start:end]
        n_start = int(n_start)
        n_end = int(n_end)
        Ax = data["Ax"][n_start:n_end]
        Ay = data["Ay"][n_start:n_end]
        Az = data["Az"][n_start:n_end]
        Lx = data["Lx"][n_start:n_end]
        Ly = data["Ly"][n_start:n_end]
        Lz = data["Lz"][n_start:n_end]
        Gx = data["Gx"][n_start:n_end]
        Gy = data["Gy"][n_start:n_end]
        Gz = data["Gz"][n_start:n_end]
        Mx = data["Mx"][n_start:n_end]
        My = data["My"][n_start:n_end]
        Mz = data["Mz"][n_start:n_end]
        if(len(data['timestamp'][n_start:n_end]) == window_size): # include only windows with size of 90
            segments = np.vstack([segments,np.dstack([Ax,Ay,Az,Gx,Gy,Gz,Mx,My,Mz])])
            labels = np.append(labels,stats.mode(data["activity"][n_start:n_end])[0][0])
    return segments, labels

def weight_variable(shape, restore_name):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev = 0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial, name=restore_name)

def bias_variable(shape, restore_name):
    initial = tf.constant(0.0, shape = shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial, name=restore_name)

def depthwise_conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(x,W, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')

def apply_depthwise_conv(x,weights,biases):
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.add(depthwise_conv2d(x, weights),biases))

def apply_max_pool(x,kernel_size,stride_size):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 1, kernel_size, 1], 
                          strides=[1, 1, stride_size, 1], padding='VALID') 

#------------------------get dataset----------------------#

## run shoaib_dataset.py to generate dataset_shoaib_total.txt

## get data from dataset_shoaib_total.txt
dataset_belt = read_data('dataset_shoaibsensoractivity_participant_belt.txt')
dataset_left_pocket = read_data('dataset_shoaibsensoractivity_participant_left_pocket.txt')
dataset_right_pocket = read_data('dataset_shoaibsensoractivity_participant_right_pocket.txt')
dataset_upper_arm = read_data('dataset_shoaibsensoractivity_participant_upper_arm.txt')
dataset_wrist = read_data('dataset_shoaibsensoractivity_participant_wrist.txt')



#--------------------preprocessing------------------------#

dataset_belt['Ax'] = feature_normalize(dataset_belt['Ax'])
dataset_belt['Ay'] = feature_normalize(dataset_belt['Ay'])
dataset_belt['Az'] = feature_normalize(dataset_belt['Az'])
dataset_belt['Gx'] = feature_normalize(dataset_belt['Gx'])
dataset_belt['Gy'] = feature_normalize(dataset_belt['Gy'])
dataset_belt['Gz'] = feature_normalize(dataset_belt['Gz'])
dataset_belt['Mx'] = feature_normalize(dataset_belt['Mx'])
dataset_belt['My'] = feature_normalize(dataset_belt['My'])
dataset_belt['Mz'] = feature_normalize(dataset_belt['Mz'])

dataset_left_pocket['Ax'] = feature_normalize(dataset_left_pocket['Ax'])
dataset_left_pocket['Ay'] = feature_normalize(dataset_left_pocket['Ay'])
dataset_left_pocket['Az'] = feature_normalize(dataset_left_pocket['Az'])
dataset_left_pocket['Gx'] = feature_normalize(dataset_left_pocket['Gx'])
dataset_left_pocket['Gy'] = feature_normalize(dataset_left_pocket['Gy'])
dataset_left_pocket['Gz'] = feature_normalize(dataset_left_pocket['Gz'])
dataset_left_pocket['Mx'] = feature_normalize(dataset_left_pocket['Mx'])
dataset_left_pocket['My'] = feature_normalize(dataset_left_pocket['My'])
dataset_left_pocket['Mz'] = feature_normalize(dataset_left_pocket['Mz'])

dataset_right_pocket['Ax'] = feature_normalize(dataset_right_pocket['Ax'])
dataset_right_pocket['Ay'] = feature_normalize(dataset_right_pocket['Ay'])
dataset_right_pocket['Az'] = feature_normalize(dataset_right_pocket['Az'])
dataset_right_pocket['Gx'] = feature_normalize(dataset_right_pocket['Gx'])
dataset_right_pocket['Gy'] = feature_normalize(dataset_right_pocket['Gy'])
dataset_right_pocket['Gz'] = feature_normalize(dataset_right_pocket['Gz'])
dataset_right_pocket['Mx'] = feature_normalize(dataset_right_pocket['Mx'])
dataset_right_pocket['My'] = feature_normalize(dataset_right_pocket['My'])
dataset_right_pocket['Mz'] = feature_normalize(dataset_right_pocket['Mz'])

dataset_upper_arm['Ax'] = feature_normalize(dataset_upper_arm['Ax'])
dataset_upper_arm['Ay'] = feature_normalize(dataset_upper_arm['Ay'])
dataset_upper_arm['Az'] = feature_normalize(dataset_upper_arm['Az'])
dataset_upper_arm['Gx'] = feature_normalize(dataset_upper_arm['Gx'])
dataset_upper_arm['Gy'] = feature_normalize(dataset_upper_arm['Gy'])
dataset_upper_arm['Gz'] = feature_normalize(dataset_upper_arm['Gz'])
dataset_upper_arm['Mx'] = feature_normalize(dataset_upper_arm['Mx'])
dataset_upper_arm['My'] = feature_normalize(dataset_upper_arm['My'])
dataset_upper_arm['Mz'] = feature_normalize(dataset_upper_arm['Mz'])


dataset_wrist['Ax'] = feature_normalize(dataset_wrist['Ax'])
dataset_wrist['Ay'] = feature_normalize(dataset_wrist['Ay'])
dataset_wrist['Az'] = feature_normalize(dataset_wrist['Az'])
dataset_wrist['Gx'] = feature_normalize(dataset_wrist['Gx'])
dataset_wrist['Gy'] = feature_normalize(dataset_wrist['Gy'])
dataset_wrist['Gz'] = feature_normalize(dataset_wrist['Gz'])
dataset_wrist['Mx'] = feature_normalize(dataset_wrist['Mx'])
dataset_wrist['My'] = feature_normalize(dataset_wrist['My'])
dataset_wrist['Mz'] = feature_normalize(dataset_wrist['Mz'])


#------------------fixed hyperparameters--------------------#

window_size = 200 #from 90 #FIXED at 4 seconds


#----------------input hyperparameters------------------#

input_height = 1
input_width = window_size
num_labels = 7
num_channels = 9 #from 3 channels #9 channels for AGM


#-------------------sliding time window----------------#

segments_belt, labels_belt = segment_signal(dataset_belt, window_size=window_size, num_channels=num_channels)
labels_belt = np.asarray(pd.get_dummies(labels_belt), dtype = np.int8)
reshaped_segments_belt = segments_belt.reshape(len(segments_belt), (window_size*num_channels)) #use variable num_channels instead of constant 3 channels

segments_left_pocket, labels_left_pocket = segment_signal(dataset_left_pocket, window_size=window_size, num_channels=num_channels)
labels_left_pocket = np.asarray(pd.get_dummies(labels_left_pocket), dtype = np.int8)
reshaped_segments_left_pocket = segments_left_pocket.reshape(len(segments_left_pocket), (window_size*num_channels)) #use variable num_channels instead of constant 3 channels

segments_right_pocket, labels_right_pocket = segment_signal(dataset_right_pocket, window_size=window_size, num_channels=num_channels)
labels_right_pocket = np.asarray(pd.get_dummies(labels_right_pocket), dtype = np.int8)
reshaped_segments_right_pocket = segments_right_pocket.reshape(len(segments_right_pocket), (window_size*num_channels)) #use variable num_channels instead of constant 3 channels

segments_upper_arm, labels_upper_arm = segment_signal(dataset_upper_arm, window_size=window_size, num_channels=num_channels)
labels_upper_arm = np.asarray(pd.get_dummies(labels_upper_arm), dtype = np.int8)
reshaped_segments_upper_arm = segments_upper_arm.reshape(len(segments_upper_arm), (window_size*num_channels)) #use variable num_channels instead of constant 3 channels

segments_wrist, labels_wrist = segment_signal(dataset_wrist, window_size=window_size, num_channels=num_channels)
labels_wrist = np.asarray(pd.get_dummies(labels_wrist), dtype = np.int8)
reshaped_segments_wrist = segments_wrist.reshape(len(segments_wrist), (window_size*num_channels)) #use variable num_channels instead of constant 3 channels



##reshaped_segments = np.vstack([reshaped_segments1,reshaped_segments2,reshaped_segments3,reshaped_segments4,reshaped_segments5,reshaped_segments6,reshaped_segments7,reshaped_segments8,reshaped_segments9,reshaped_segments10])
##labels = np.vstack([labels1,labels2,labels3,labels4,labels5,labels6,labels7,labels8,labels9,labels10])



# all locations
reshaped_segments = np.vstack([reshaped_segments_belt,reshaped_segments_left_pocket,reshaped_segments_right_pocket,reshaped_segments_upper_arm,reshaped_segments_wrist])
labels = np.vstack([labels_belt,labels_left_pocket,labels_right_pocket,labels_upper_arm,labels_wrist]) 


#------------divide data into test and training `set-----------#

train_test_split = np.random.rand(len(reshaped_segments)) < 0.70
train_x = reshaped_segments[train_test_split]
train_y = labels[train_test_split]
test_x = reshaped_segments[~train_test_split]
test_y = labels[~train_test_split]



#---------------training hyperparameters----------------#

batch_size = 10
kernel_size = 60 #from 60 #optimal 2
depth = 15 #from 60 #optimal 15
num_hidden = 1000 #from 1000 #optimal 80

learning_rate = 0.0001
training_epochs = 8


total_batches = train_x.shape[0] ##// batch_size # included // batch_size



#---------define placeholders for input----------#

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,input_width * num_channels], name="input")
X_reshaped = tf.reshape(X,[-1,input_height,input_width,num_channels])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,num_labels])


#---------------------perform convolution-----------------#

# first convolutional layer 
c_weights = weight_variable([1, kernel_size, num_channels, depth], restore_name="c_weights")
c_biases = bias_variable([depth * num_channels], restore_name="c_biases")

c = apply_depthwise_conv(X_reshaped,c_weights,c_biases)
p = apply_max_pool(c,20,2)

# second convolutional layer
c2_weights = weight_variable([1, 6,depth*num_channels,depth//10], restore_name="c2_weights")
c2_biases = bias_variable([(depth*num_channels)*(depth//10)], restore_name="c2_biases")

c2 = apply_depthwise_conv(p,c2_weights,c2_biases)


n_classes = 7
n_hidden = 128
n_inputs = 540 # 540 = 60*3 not 180 # or 7*9*10
lstm_size = 128

rnnW = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_inputs, n_hidden])),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes]))
}

rnnBiases = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden], mean=1.0)),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

c2Reshape = tf.reshape(c2, [-1, 7, 200])
shuff = tf.transpose(c2Reshape, [1, 0, 2])
shuff = tf.reshape(shuff, [-1, n_inputs])

# Linear activation, reshaping inputs to the LSTM's number of hidden:
hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(
    shuff, rnnW['hidden']
) + rnnBiases['hidden'])

# Split the series because the rnn cell needs time_steps features, each of shape:
hidden = tf.split(axis=0, num_or_size_splits=7, value=hidden)

lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(lstm_size, forget_bias=1.0)
# Stack two LSTM layers, both layers has the same shape
lstm_layers = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * 2)

lstmOutputs, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_layers, hidden, dtype=tf.float32)
lstmLastOutput = lstmOutputs[-1]
y_ = tf.matmul(lstmLastOutput, rnnW['output']) + rnnBiases['output']





#-----------------loss optimization-------------#

loss = -tf.reduce_sum(Y * tf.log(y_))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(loss)
##optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(loss)


#-----------------compute accuracy---------------#

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_,1), tf.argmax(Y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

cost_history = np.empty(shape=[1],dtype=float)
saver = tf.train.Saver()



#-----------------run session--------------------#

session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for epoch in range(8):
    for b in range(total_batches):    
        offset = (b * batch_size) % (train_y.shape[0] - batch_size)
        batch_x = train_x[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        batch_y = train_y[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        _, c = session.run([optimizer, loss],feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y : batch_y})
        cost_history = np.append(cost_history,c)
    print("Epoch: ",epoch," Training Loss: ",c," Training Accuracy: ",\
            session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: train_x, Y: train_y}))

print("Testing Accuracy:", session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: test_x, Y: test_y}))

if 1==1:
    print ("Testing Accuracy: ", session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: test_x, Y: test_y}),'\n')
    pred_y = session.run(tf.argmax(y_ ,1),feed_dict={X: test_x})
    cm = confusion_matrix(np.argmax(test_y ,1),pred_y)
    print (cm, '\n')
    plt.imshow(cm)
    plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
    plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'afmhot'
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(['Wal', 'Std', 'Jog', 'Sit', 'Bik', 'Wlu', 'Wld']))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, ['Wal', 'Std', 'Jog', 'Sit', 'Bik', 'Wlu', 'Wld'])
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, ['Wal', 'Std', 'Jog', 'Sit', 'Bik', 'Wlu', 'Wld'])

    fmt = '.2f'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    plt.figure()
    plt.show()
```

However, I always get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1322, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)   File "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1307, in _run_fn
>       options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
>       run_metadata) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
>   Incompatible shapes: [10,7] vs. [20,7]     [[Node: mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0, Log)]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 6, in
>   
>       _, c = session.run([optimizer, loss],feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y : batch_y})   File
>   "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 900, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1135, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1316, in _do_run
>       run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1335, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
>   Incompatible shapes: [10,7] vs. [20,7]     [[Node: mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0, Log)]]
>
> Caused by op 'mul', defined at:   File "", line 1, in 
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\idlelib\run.py",
>   line 130, in main
>       ret = method(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\idlelib\run.py",
>   line 357, in runcode
>       exec(code, self.locals)   File "", line 2, in    File
>   "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py",
>   line 979, in binary_op_wrapper
>       return func(x, y, name=name)   File "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py",
>   line 1211, in _mul_dispatch
>       return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name=name)   File "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py",
>   line 5066, in mul
>       "Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)   File "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 787, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 3392, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\Charlene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1718, in **init**
>       self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes:
>   [10,7] vs. [20,7]      [[Node: mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0, Log)]]

The main error here I see is:

> Incompatible shapes: [10,7] vs. [20,7]

where 10 is the batch size and 7 is the number of classes.

What is cuasing the error?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the error happens here:

```
loss = -tf.reduce_sum(Y * tf.log(y_))
```

Your `Y` is `(10, 7)`, which is expected, but `y_` for some reason is `(20, 7)`.

Try tracing the shape of `c2` before this line:

```
c2Reshape = tf.reshape(c2, [-1, 7, 200])
```

And the shape of `c2Reshape` after it (or just replace for the time being that line with `c2Reshape = tf.reshape(c2, [10, 7, 200])` and see if it fails), I suspect that this is where the 20 comes from.

Comment: When I tried to change the batch size to 20 that `y_` will be (20,7), the shape change to (40,7).

Comment: I am actually not suggesting changing the batch size. The most likely cause of the issue is that your shape in the resize is wrong. One like way to fix it is to change that resize to `c2Reshape = tf.reshape(c2, [-1, 7, 400])`, but I haven't read your entire model, there's a good chance the issue happens somewhere before that.

Comment: i tried `c2Reshape = tf.reshape(c2, [10, 7, 200])` and I got this error

Comment: ValueError: Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 7560 but is 14000 for 'Reshape_1' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [?,1,56,135], [3] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [10,7,200].

Comment: So effectively your `c2` is `(batch_size, 1, 56, 135)` and you are resizing it to `(?, 7, 200)`, which seems wrong to me. Shall it be `(?, 7, 1080)`? Where does `(?, 7, 200)` come from?